# Is there an alternative to LookupPageId but on the page?

Tags: dynamics-business-central, dynamics-al, businesscentral

Instead of specifying a LookupPageId on the source table is there any other way to make a lookup behave like this without adjusting the table:

[image]

Without the LookupPageId the lookup just looks like this, without the New button:
[image]

*BC-22*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no other way than providing the LookupPageId. *New* needs thatpage to be able to show something.